# firefox: download javascript file using the file protocol?

Tags: javascript, firefox, download

When I paste this on the address bar: "file:///C:/script.js"

Firefox shows the contents of the js file, but I want that download dialog to appear instead.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure the same thing happens naturally for http(s)...

Comment: doesn't seem to be related to programming... just press Ctrl+S

Comment: If you're serving this file from a web application, you could set the content type to enforce this, but just reading from the local file system...not sure there's a lot you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be related to programming... just press Ctrl+S

---

If you want to force download prompt programmatically:

```
function downloadPrompt(url) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = a.href.substr(a.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/Sbp5M/

only seems to be working in Google Chrome though.

Comment: @user2634522 it will probably come in near future https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676619